# server side rendering react Issue rendering a subroute

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

I have a route: /events with a subroute /events/:id

I created a reducer and an action for fetching all the events and display them in the eventsPage.

This part works fine.

Now from the events page, when I click on an event I'm trying to navigate to /events/:id

In the events/:id page I created an action which is called in the componendDidMount callback then display the event from there. 
It works fine when I click on a link to an event's details page from the list. Now I'm looking for the way to perform the request on the server side so when I do a full reload of the page, the selected event is still displayed.

Here is my events/:id page component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchEvent} from '../actions/eventsActions'

class EventDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            event: null
        }

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchEvent(this.props.match.params.slug).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                event: response.event
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
function loadData(store){    

}

export default {
    component: connect(null, {fetchEvent})(EventDetail),
    loadData
};
```

my fetch_event action

```
import {FETCH_EVENT} from './types';
export const fetchEvent = (event_slug) => async(dispatch, getState, api) => {
    const res = await api.get(`/api/events/${event_slug}`);
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_EVENT,
        payload: res.data
    })
    return res.data;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by `when I reload the page nothing happens.` Do you get any error? `/events/:id` is this route handled on server? Also, which request is not made to server: the page request for `/events/:id` or the action in componentDidMount`. Can you post your code here as well as the error (if any) you are getting?

Comment: @sunil thanks for replying.
I just updated the question